# Does GNU make implicitly compile .c files to .o files?

Tags: c, makefile, cc

Noob question. I want to compile *bar.c* with object file *foo.o* to an executable *bar*.
I have this in a Makefile:

```
bar: foo.o 
    cc bar.c foo.o -o bar
```

I run `$ make -n` and get :

```
cc    -c -o foo.o foo.c 
cc bar.c foo.o -o bar
```

I'm looking at the first line of output `cc    -c -o foo.o foo.c`.  I didn't write an explicit rule compiling *foo.c* to *foo.o*. Does `make` do this implicitly when it sees a *.o* target?

Comment: Indeed. See [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules), under "Compiling C programs".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, GNU make has a [catalog](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) of built-in rules:

> *Compiling C programs*
> n.o is made automatically from n.c with a recipe of the form ‘$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c’.

> *Linking a single object file*
> n is made automatically from n.o by running the linker (usually called ld) via the C compiler. The precise recipe used is ‘$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)’.

so you could just write:

```
bar: bar.o foo.o
```